# UWP IsNullOrEmptyStateTrigger not working for ListView

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

The XAML below is for a UWP app uses a VisualStateManager with an `IsNullOrEmptyStateTrigger` from the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI package. The trigger is supposed to disable the button when no items are selected from the ListView. However, the button always remains enabled.

The ListView's `SelectedItem` should be null when nothing in the list is selected (nothing is selected when you first run the app). Any ideas?

My code is loosely based on [this example](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/rel/7.1.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/Triggers/IsNullOrEmptyStateTrigger.bind).

```
<Page
    x:Class="UwpTriggerDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UwpTriggerDemo"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:triggers="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Triggers"    
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <StackPanel>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ListViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="ListSomethingSelectedState" />
                <VisualState x:Name="ListNothingSelectedState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <triggers:IsNullOrEmptyStateTrigger Value="{Binding SelectedItem, 
                            ElementName=myListView, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="myButton.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>

        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <ListView x:Name="myListView">
            <TextBlock Text="Item 1" />
            <TextBlock Text="Item 2" />
            <TextBlock Text="Item 3" />
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="Click Me" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UWP IsNullOrEmptyStateTrigger not working for ListView

We could reproduce your problem, please feel free post this problem in `WindowsCommunityToolkit` issue box. And currently the is a workaround that control myButton's status manually. Make `IsEnable` property in code behind and bind it to myButton. And update IsEnable value in the `SelectItem` set method. For more please refer to the following code.

```
private bool _isEnable;
public bool IsEnable
{
    get
    {
        return _isEnable;
    }
    set
    {
        _isEnable = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
private string _selectItem;
public string SelectItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selectItem;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectItem = value;
        if(_selectItem == null)
        {
            IsEnable = false;
        }
        else
        {
            IsEnable = true;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<ListView
    x:Name="myListView"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"       
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <x:String>Hello</x:String>
    <x:String>Hello</x:String>
    <x:String>Hello</x:String>
    <x:String>Hello</x:String>
</ListView>
<Button
    x:Name="myButton"
    Content="Click Me"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnable}" />
```